# QT5.7 - Why i get a malformed json value with QString but perfect with std::string?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, json, qt, qstring

I try to get a json response from an api in Ruby On Rails.

When I call this url directly with **curl** or **postman** I get a perfect json response.

When I use my program with QT5.7 windows compiled in Static for a program in 32bits, I get a perfect response only if use **std::string**.

But, if I use QDebug for print a **QString()** I get this malformed and Strange result :

> "{\"success\":true,\"files\":[\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlcn.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldata.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldebguts.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldelta.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldiag.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldoc.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldos.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldsc.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldtrace.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlebcdic.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlembed.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlexperiment.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq1.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq2.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq3.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq4.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq5.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq6.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq7.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq8.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq9.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfilter.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfork.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlform.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfreebsd.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfunc.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlgit.pod\",\"C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlglossaîv

So, if I print **std::string**, I have a perfect json, exactly what i want :

> {"success":true,"files":["C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlcn.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldata.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldebguts.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldelta.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldiag.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldoc.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldos.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldsc.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perldtrace.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlebcdic.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlembed.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlexperiment.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq1.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq2.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq3.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq4.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq5.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq6.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq7.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq8.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfaq9.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfilter.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfork.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlform.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfreebsd.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlfunc.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlgit.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlglossary.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlgpl.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlguts.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlhack.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlhacktips.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlhacktut.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlhaiku.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlhist.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlhpux.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlhurd.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlintern.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlinterp.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlintro.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perliol.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlipc.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlirix.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perljp.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlko.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perllexwarn.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perllinux.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perllocale.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perllol.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlmacos.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlmacosx.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlmod.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlmodinstall.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlmodlib.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlmodstyle.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlmroapi.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlnetware.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlnewmod.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlnumber.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlobj.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlootut.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlop.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlopenbsd.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlopentut.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlos2.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlos390.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlos400.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlpacktut.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlperf.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlplan9.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlpod.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlpodspec.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlpodstyle.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlpolicy.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlport.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlpragma.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlqnx.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlre.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlreapi.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlrebackslash.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlrecharclass.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlref.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlreftut.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlreguts.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlrepository.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlrequick.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlreref.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlretut.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlriscos.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlrun.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlsec.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlsolaris.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlsource.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlstyle.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlsub.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlsymbian.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlsyn.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlsynology.pod","C:/Perl/lib/pods/perlthrtut.pod"]}

I have no idea what i can do because i need to parse my json with QString for QJsonDocument and QJsonObject.

I have try many things like 
[QNetworkAccessManager](http://pastebin.com/Nh1rAacr)

Or (ugly thing for understand and debug) like : 
[Curl external](http://pastebin.com/qAYsdrjx)

Thanks

Comment: can't you just convert the std string to a qstring afterwards?

Comment: Thanks for the mistake, we talk about QT5.7

Comment: Yes, i'have try but is still the same result, i tried to convert wih QBytesArray  and still the same too

Comment: Do you know at what letter the strings start to look different? When you compare the size of the strings? are they different?

Comment: This does not really look like it should cause problems. Either you just have an issue with the debug output or the error seems to be somewhere in the code.

Comment: @Sacha Ifrah qDebug() print the data in debug format(developer friendly).
But of you want to use std::string and convert it into QString. You can use the following code.

    std::string data;
    // .. fill data
    QString data1 = QString::fromUtf8( data.c_str() );

But it show the same result with qDebug()( with " and \)

Comment: Is it not possible to compare because is it random and as you can see, no special char Inside the good json format

Comment: The problem is not just qDebug() because when i try to convert to Json string  with QJsonDocument QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonString.toUtf8()); , this will be an empty value. He can't read on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `qDebug()` for stdout output? This is not what it should be used for.

It displays, in debug format, the current contents of many types. For `QString` it means the string in quotes with certain character - double quote included - escaped with \. That doesn't mean the string itself contains escaped data. It's only presented to you like that by `QDebug`.

Comment: The problem is not just qDebug() because when i try to convert to Json string with QJsonDocument QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonString.toUtf8()); , this will be an empty value. He can't read on it

Comment: Would you mind posting the actual code in the question then?

Comment: @SachaIfrah So, at the same time `jsonObj` is empty and `jsonString` is not?

Comment: jsonObj is empty and jsonString is not empty yes.

Comment: @SachaIfrah try pasting your json data to http://jsonlint.com/ and see if it's valid. Also, `QJsonDocument::fromJson` also has an overload taking a pointer to error variable. Try using it.